# Install Php-pear to /usr/share Raspbian (debian)

Tags: linux, debian, php, raspberry-pi

I am running Raspbian on my Pi and have installed PHP-pear, I have some software that requires PHP-pear but is normally installed on a Fedora based machine so pear is normally found at /usr/share/pear

But the default install location for debian is /usr/share/php/PEAR
Would it be possible to change the install location to /usr/share/pear ?
I have tried creating a symbolic link from /usr/share/php/PEAR to /usr/share/pear but that dosnt seem to work (Still get an error in the software saying it failed to open required 'PEAR/command.php').

Any ideas would be great!

Pear was installed using

```
apt-get install php-pear
```

I had created the link using

```
ln -l /usr/share/php/PEAR /usr/share/pear
```

And the error the program gives:

> "Fatal error: require_once(): Failed oepning required
>   'PEAR/Command.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear')"

Comment: Please include some more details. _How_ did you install it? Which command did you use to create the symlink? WHat is the exact error? When do you get it? etc etc

Comment: Ok updated :) @terdon